# possible outputs of code with fork()

Tags: c, fork

Given the following short code, I find it quite difficult to find out the possible printed values of a and b:

```
main()
{
            int a,b;
 
    if ( ( a=fork() ) || ( b=fork() ) )
            printf ( "a=%d,b=%d\n" , a , b );

}
```

I guess I fail with understanding which one the father process or the son process are.

As far as I can understand it, the print will be done only if a=0 or b=0. Suppose a=0, we get 2 printed lines (becuase of using fork) of this:

```
a=0, b=garbage value
```

Suppose b=0, we get 2 printed lines of this:

```
a=garbage value, b=0
```

Of course, there could be no output in case fork does not succeed.

I am sure I am wrong  in someplace ..any help would be appreaciated.

Answer (score 2):

> As far as I can understand it, the print will be done only if a=0 or b=0

This is backward.  The print will happen when one of the expressions on either side of `||` is *nonzero*.  It also seems like you may also not know that the expression on the right-hand side of `||` is only evaluated if the expression on the left-hand side is zero; this is called *short-circuit evaluation*.  (Similarly, the right-hand side of `&&` is only evaluated if the left-hand side is nonzero.)

Assuming that no calls to `fork` fail, there are only three branches of execution, because each process calls `fork` at most once.  `printf` is called twice.

- original process: `a=fork()` sets `a` to a nonzero value

  - the left side of `||` is nonzero, so the right side is not evaluated
  - `printf` is called with `a` nonzero and `b` uninitialized
- child process: `a=fork()` sets `a` to zero

  - the left side of `||` is zero, so the right side is evaluated
  - `b=fork()` sets `b` to a nonzero value
  - the right side of `||` is nonzero
  - `printf` is called with `a` zero and `b` nonzero
- grandchild process: `b=fork()` sets `b` to zero

  - both the left and right sides of `||` are zero
  - printf is not called

The output from the child and original processes may appear in either possible order.  Since `printf` is only called *after* each process is done making calls to `fork`, one need not worry about duplicated buffered output.

Because of the "short-circuit" behavior of `||` and the order of evaluation of `(x=fork())`, you never compare an uninitialized value to zero, but you do pass an uninitialized value to `printf` on one branch of execution.  This is a bug.  You should initialize both `a` and `b` to zero when they are declared, for readability.  Also, their type should be `pid_t` (and you should include `unistd.h` as well as `stdio.h`).

Incidentally, every time you put spaces on the inside of your parentheses, or on the left-hand side of a comma, God kills a kitten.  Please, think of the kittens.

Incidentally, if you have `fork` you're on Unix, which does not support declaring `main` with return type `void`.  You should write `int main(void)` instead.  You should also end the body of main with `return 0;` this is technically not necessary in C99 and later, but there are an awful lot of compilers still out there that default to C89, and anyway I think relying on implicit return 0 is bad style.

**EDIT**, since I see you addressed this by changing your code to declare `main()` with no return type at all: that technically does declare it to return `int`, but relies on an obsolescent feature called "implicit int".  This is considered to be *egregiously* bad style nowadays.  Some people will even tell you that "implicit int" has been removed from the language, which is true if you go by the letter of the standard, but false if you go by what compilers actually accept.  It's also wrong to put nothing between the argument parentheses; in C, that doesn't declare a function that takes no arguments, it declares a function that takes an *unspecified number* of arguments.  (Again, if you go by the letter of the standard, a function *definition* with empty argument parentheses does declare it to take no arguments, but that's not the case going by what compilers actually accept.)